# Dart destruction workround?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add some file logging to code invoked by the Workmanager package.  The callback has the general structure of the callback routine starting another async task, viz:

```
Future<void> callbackDispatcher() async {
  .
  .
  .
  Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    .
    .
    .
    return Future.value(true);
  });
  .
  .
  .
}
```

At the conclusion of whichever of these two routines finishes *last*, iiuc, I need to do:

```
   iosink.close();
   await iosink.done;
```

before I can exit/return.

As dart doesn't have destructors, I'm not sure how best to accomplish this.  I've written the following which, while it seems to work, is rather fragile and somewhat hokey:

```
class LogWriter2 {
  static final File _callbackLogFile = getLocalFile( "callbackLog.out" );
  static IOSink _writer;
  static int _instanceCount = 0;

  LogWriter2._privateConstructor() {
    //_writer = _callbackLogFile.openWrite(mode: FileMode.append);
  }

  static final LogWriter2 _instance = LogWriter2._privateConstructor();

  factory LogWriter2() {
    if (_instanceCount <= 0) {
      debugPrint("${dt.now} constr: opening writer...");
      _writer = _callbackLogFile.openWrite(mode: FileMode.append);
    }

    _instanceCount++;
    debugPrint("${dt.now} constr: instanceCount++ now $_instanceCount");

    return _instance;
  }

  writeln(String string) {
    var dtn = dt.now;
    _writer.writeln("${dtn} $string");
    debugPrint("${dtn} lw2.writeln: $string");
  }

  close() async {
    _instanceCount--;
    debugPrint("${dt.now} close: instanceCount-- now $_instanceCount");

    if (_instanceCount <= 0) {
      debugPrint("${dt.now} close: closing writer...");

      await _writer.flush(); // close() does not guarantee flush!
      _writer.close(); 
      await _writer.done;

      debugPrint("${dt.now} close: close complete");
    }
  }
}
// nb.  Don't use this code as-is as it has a race condition that is fixed
// with a mutex (omitted here).  Message me if you need a working version.
```

Can someone suggest a better way of achieving this?

Comment: I don't think it's hokey; that's what you have to do if you need reference-counting, and reference-counting is what you need to identify the last reference.

Comment: It's not hokey to have the forethought to manually dispose your resources when you are done with them rather than rely on destructor code to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys.  I'm new to dart and was hoping there was a more robust/elegant way of achieving this that I'd overlooked.